# ¿Cómo puedo crear un array que contenga otro array al que se le pueda cambiar el tamaño? en C++

Tags: c++

Arrays:

```
new array A[n];

A[0]=B[]
```

Quiero que B esté dentro de A

Funciones que cambien el tamaño a B:

```
void agrandar(B);
void achicar(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa `std::vector`:

```
using formacion = std::vector<int>;
using formacion_doble = std::vector<formacion>;

formacion_doble f(n, {}); // Una formación de 'n' elementos inicializados a conjunto vacío ({}).
```

Para agrandar o encoger un elemento arbitrario:

```
f[elemento].resize(nuevo_tamaño);
```